# Android - How do I set two id names to the same value in XML (preferably)?

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

Basically, I want to do something like this:

```
<resources>
    <item name="my_play" type="id">@id/exo_play</item>
</resources>
```

So that later on I can define something like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/my_play"
...
```

... and that `ImageView` would get the same id as `@id/exo_play`. Of course, this syntax does not work.

Why? Well, I am tasked with wrapping/ extending ExoPlayer. I need to expose the video controls customisation functionality which requires you to use ExoPlayer's ids. I also need to obfuscate the fact that Exoplayer provides the core functionality - just in case we decide to swap it out later.

You can wrap the id in a `style` but this breaks down in Relative and Constraint Layouts which require ids for positioning. You can also have your id refered to by an integer:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="my_play" type="id">@id/exo_play</item>
</resources>
```

- The ide complains but it compiles - Then define your view like this:

```
<ImageView android:id="@integer/my_play"
...
```

... but that is really nasty and breaks as soon as you add something with the Design View anyway.

So to be clear, `@id/exo_play` is defined in the ExoPlayer library and will have a unique integer value assigned to it in the generated `R` class. I need my `@id/my_play` to have the same value assigned to it. Yes, I know. The whole idea is that ids are unique and I'm trying to break that.

Is this something that can be defined in the `build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new values resource file, e.g. `res/values/ids.xml` with the following content:

```
<resources>
    <id name="exo_viewer"/>
</resources>
```

You can refer to this static definition as usual in XML as "@id/exo_viewer" and in Java as R.id.exo_viewer.  No complaints from the IDE or compiler problems.  Just don't override it in your layout XML definitions using the "@+id/exo_viewer" syntax.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough with my question. Let's say I was trying to replace ExoPlayer's 'play' button. Exoplayer would be looking for a view with an id with the value of 'exo_play' defined (in the same way as you have above) in it's library. I can't just make up my own ids with their own value (like exo_viewer) because this will be given a unique value that won't be recognised by ExoPlayer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your question a bit more carefully.  Would I be right in saying this sounds like a similar situation to passing a custom layout to an `ArrayAdapter` and using `@android:id/text1` to label the text view in the custom layout? 

Do you have visibility of the exoplayer's generated R file as an import, or by inspection?

Comment: I've not heard of the `ArrayAdapter` situation you describe, but if you *have* to label the text view `@android:id/text1` in order for it to work then yes, maybe. I'm not sure about the `R` class visibility from exoplayer. Let's say I can import it. How would that help?

Comment: It's not an area I'm familar with, but if you are importing the Exoplayer library through a gradle "api" or "implementation" directive in build.gradle, this should expose any public ids available in the Exoplayer's aar file.   These should be referencable through an xmlns definition like:
`xmlns:exoplayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/java.com.google.android.exoplayer2"`, then refer to this in your own XML as `"@exoplayer:id/exo_play"`.  But that's more speculation on my part than from experience.  Of course even this won't work if the ids you are needing are private in the library.

Comment: But that may also be missing the point, if you want to define local ids to be the same values as those from the library.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.